# Don't know why getting segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to solve [The Grid Search](https://www.hackerrank.com/rest/contests/master/challenges/the-grid-search/download_pdf?language=English) using C++ in Xcode, and having some strange output.

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int tCases;
    cin >> tCases;
    for(int i = 0; i < tCases; i++){
        bool isFound = false;
        int row = 0, column = 0, tRow = 0, tColumn = 0, p = 0;
        cin >> row >> column;
        vector<string> matrix(row);
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            cin >> matrix[i];
        }
        cin >> tRow >> tColumn;
        vector<string> tMatrix(tRow);
        for (int i = 0; i < tRow; i++) {
            cin >> tMatrix[i];
        }
        vector<long> position(tRow);
        for (int i = 0; i <= row - tRow; i++) {
            position[p] = matrix[i].find(tMatrix[p]) ;
            if (position[p] == string::npos) {
                isFound = false;
                p = 0;
            }
            else if (p != tRow && (p == 0 || position[p] == position[p-1])) {
                isFound = true;
                p++;
            }
            else if (p == tRow)
                break;
        }
        cout << (isFound ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Test Case 1:**

```
1
20 20
34889246430321978567
58957542800420926643
35502505614464308821
14858224623252492823
72509980920257761017
22842014894387119401
01112950562348692493
16417403478999610594
79426411112116726706
65175742483779283052
89078730337964397201
13765228547239925167
26113704444636815161
25993216162800952044
88796416233981756034
14416627212117283516
15248825304941012863
88460496662793369385
59727291023618867708
19755940017808628326
7 4
1641
7942
6517
8907
1376
2691
2599
```

**My Output & Expected Output:**

> NO

**Test Case 2:**

```
1
25 25
7652157548860692421022503
9283597467877865303553675
4160389485250089289309493
2583470721457150497569300
3220130778636571709490905
3588873017660047694725749
9288991387848870159567061
4840101673383478700737237
8430916536880190158229898
8986106490042260460547150
2591460395957631878779378
1816190871689680423501920
0704047294563387014281341
8544774664056811258209321
9609294756392563447060526
0170173859593369054590795
6088985673796975810221577
7738800757919472437622349
5474120045253009653348388
3930491401877849249410013
1486477041403746396925337
2955579022827592919878713
2625547961868100985291514
3673299809851325174555652
4533398973801647859680907
5 4
5250
1457
8636
7660
7848
```

**My Output & Expected Output:**

> YES

Funny thing is that when I try to check both test cases together, it just gives me the output for first test case, and then kept running without showing anything. HackerRank is saying it's having segmentation fault. However, I ran the combined test case in CLion and worked fine. Would you please help me find the fault in my code?

Comment: I don't believe this `(position[p] == string::npos)` should ever be true.  Your intent is `(position[p] == (long)string::npos)`  If `position` contained `std::size_t` instead of `long` that would avoid all such architecture dependent pitfalls.

Comment: I went through through the code using break points, and yes when it doesn't get a match, position[p]  becomes -1 and (position[p] == string::npos) becomes true.

Comment: @JSF: signed/unsigned comarison will work fine here. It's not perfect but it works.

Comment: Exactly. It's not perfect though it works.

Comment: @abu.saeid I'm just sick of that kind of triva stuff appearing here,  please consider deleting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are off by one;

Replace

```
    else if (p == tRow)
        break;
```

by

```
if (p == tRow)
    break;
```

Comment: If you use Linux, I would suggest you to use valgrind on your program to identify quickly such errors

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= row - tRow; i++)
{
    position[p] = matrix[i].find(tMatrix[p]) ;
    if (position[p] == string::npos)
    {
        isFound = false;
        p = 0;
    }
    else if (p != tRow && (p == 0 || position[p] == position[p-1])) 
    {
        isFound = true;
        p++;
    }
    else if (p == tRow)
        break;
    }
}
```

This can lead to a seg fault:

- If `p` reaches `tRow-1` (why not!) and then if `position[p] == string::npos` (why not!), then you enter the first `else if` statement and do: `isFound = true; p++;`
- Then, next iteration, `p` is `tRow` (as you incremented it) you'll then test `(position[p] == string::npos)`. Accessing `position` at `tRow` index, which is out of bound.

Loop condition

```
for (int i = 0; i <= row - tRow; i++)
```

should be replaced by

```
for (int i = 0; (i <= row - tRow) && (p < tRow); i++)
```

to prevent that. And then you `else` statement (`if (p == tRow) break;`) can simply be removed.

Comment: Got your point. Such a silly mistake I made lol. Thanks a lot :)